# Using another laptop's keyboard as Macbook Pro's input device

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have my HP Spectre X360 & a Macbook Pro

The question about using HP Spectre's keyboard as an input device for the Macbook Pro. Is it possible? if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Synergy: https://symless.com/synergy. I had good results with it in the past .